# Why are the memory addresses on a 5x5 matrix separated by 4?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have been studying pointers in C, and from my readings the memory address allocation for matrices follow a linear pattern, even though a matrix is 2D. I made an experiment with a simple algorithm to print the address of each matrix element, and I am trying to understand its results. It is following a 4 by 4 pattern, even though the matrix is 5x5. Why is that? Shouldnt it follow a 1 by 1 pattern like "1, 2, 3..."?

```
int main()
{
    int size = 5;
    int matriz[size][size];
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = rand();
            printf("Address %d\n", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the reason you are confused coming from the fact that `&matriz[i][j] + 1` leads to the next value?

Comment: Side note: The correct way to print an address is to cast it to `void*` and to use the `%p` format specifier. So it should be like this: `printf("Address %p\n", (void*)&matriz[i][j]);` I believe the code that you are using will not work on a 64-bit platform, where the size of a pointer is not identical to the size of an `int`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I don't see the need for a cast.

Comment: @PaulSanders: The ISO C standard [explicitly states](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8) that `%p` must be a "pointer to void". Therefore, strictly speaking, not performing the cast to `void*` will cause undefined behavior according to the standard. The reason for this is that [the standard doesn't require all pointer types to have the same memory representation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28). However, on most modern platforms, the memory representation is the same for all pointer types, so it will most likely not be an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your system, `sizeof(int)` is 4. Every int takes 4 bytes. So the address of each next int is 4 higher.

Try a different type, like char, short, or double.

Answer (score 4):

The elements of the matrix are of type `int`.  An `int` is apparently 4 bytes wide on your system, so each element of the matrix is 4 bytes apart in memory.